# Tengo problemas con utf8 en php, subiendo un archivo .csv, con caracteres especiales(ÓÉÍÚÖÑ)

Tags: mysql, csv, carga

Estoy trabajando con mysql, intente hacerlo cambiando el cotejamiento utf8_general_ci,a utf8_spanish_ci a utf8_unicode_ci, pero ni con eso se resolvio el problema, incluso desde mi clase en php, con htmlentities pero nada,agradeceria si alguien pudiera ayudarme, mil gracias,Dios los bendiga

Comment: Si lees y pones en práctica [todo lo explicado aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967) tu problema quedará resuelto y te ahorrará futuros problemas relativos a la codificación. Si haciendo todo lo dicho allí no funciona debes revisar en el origen del archivo si éste se está creando con la codificación adecuada. Por lo que comentas parece que en tu caso el problema estaría al crear la conexión.

Comment: si tu cotejamiento es en base a utf8 no podrás subir caracteres como la ó por ser esta un carácter no estandard prueba usando $var=mb_convert_encoding($var,"Latin1","auto");